# How to get professions on world of warcraft vanilla's addon?

Tags: api, lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm creating an AddOn for a private server of World of Warcraft 1.12.1/Classic/Vanilla and I need to check the user's professions.

The information I got was the APIs `GetProfessions()` and `GetProfessionInfo()` but I can't find out how to use them.

I wanna have a variable for each profession.

It's something like this:

```
prof1, prof2, archaeology, fishing, cooking, firstAid = GetProfessions()
Profession1 = GetProfessionInfo(prof1)
Profession2 = GetProfessionInfo(prof2)
Profession3 = GetProfessionInfo(archaeology)
Profession4 = GetProfessionInfo(fishing)
Profession5 = GetProfessionInfo(cooking)
Profession6 = GetProfessionInfo(firstAid)
```

Comment: Is the problem in that you can't find the docs or the docs is not clear enough?

Comment: @werediver I can't put the code working.

Comment: What exactly happens what you call "not working"? Expand your question more.

Comment: @werediver I get a in-game red error message saying: "attempt to call global getprofessions (a nil value)".

Comment: Lua is case-sensitive.  Are you using `getprofessions` or `GetProfessions`?

Answer (score 1):

Quick glance shows there are no special tradeskill functions in API in 1.12.1. AFAIR professions were just regular entries in the spellbook back then. As such you can iterate over spellbook with [`GetSpellName`](http://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetSpellName) and check that either first return matches name of known profession or second return matches name of a known profession rank.

Additional info on each profession can be retrieved with [`GetTradeSkillLine`](http://wow.gamepedia.com/API_GetTradeSkillLine), but only when this profession is opened in tradeskill window (i.e. window where you see list of items to craft).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, `GetProfessions()` returns a table. You could always try a different way around the problem, like so:

```
professions = GetProfessions()
Profession1 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[1])
Profession2 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[2])
Profession3 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[3])
Profession4 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[4])
Profession5 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[5])
Profession6 = GetProfessionInfo(professions[6])
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but I figured I could weigh in my opinion. I have never done anything with World of Warcraft.